# Wordpress widget in custom theme

Tags: php, plugins, widgets

I created a custom theme and writing a basic widget for my wordpress based website. If I paste the code in functions.php the code works fine, however if I paste the code in a separate file and keep it in the plugins directory, it doesn't show up in the admin > appearance > widgets.

The problem to keep the widget code in functions.php is it collides with some plugins I care.

I tried wp_register_widget as a wild guess but to no avail.

Here is the widget code (You can remove the 'include' line to test the code)

```
class Similar_Apps_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {

       parent::__construct(
        'Similar_Apps_Widget', // Base ID
        __('Similar Apps', 'text_domain'), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'Similar Apps Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) 
        );
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

         ?> <h4>Similar Apps</h4> <?php
         include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/include/' . get_field('similarapps'). '-similar-products.php');

    }
}
register_widget( 'Similar_Apps_Widget' );
```

and here is the functions.php code where I define the widgets placement

```
<?php 

if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Widgetized Area',
    'id'   => 'widgetized-area',
    'description'   => 'This is a widgetized area.',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Page Widget',
    'id'   => 'page-widget',
    'description'   => 'Page Widgets.',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>'
));

}


?>
```

and here is where it is inserted into the theme

```
<div id="page-widget">

    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('page-widget')) :     else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to hook your widget registering like that:

```
add_action("widgets_init", "register_widgets");// Hook WP

/**
 * Register widgets
 */
function register_widgets() {
    require_once "FooWidget.php";
    register_widget("FooWidget");
}
```

Same for the widget zones

```
add_action("widgets_init", "register_widgets_zones");

function register_widgets_zones() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        "name" => "Foo Zone Page",
        "id" => "foo-zone-widgets",
        "class" => "panel",
        "before_widget" => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        "after_widget" => "</div>",
        "before_title" => "",
        "after_title" => "",
    ));
```

Comment: Where do I need to put that code?

I tried in **functions.php** but it breaks the code. Tried first part in **my-custom-widget.php** and the second in **functions.php** but no success.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to put this declarations in your functions.php... What eroor did you get ?

Comment: White blank page with a error in widgets.php on console.  _The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range._  
---
 I modified your code as  
    `add_action("widgets_init", "register_widgets");// Hook WP
    function register_widgets() {
    require_once "similar-apps-widget/similar-apps-widget.php";
    register_widget("Similar_Apps_Widget");
    }`
  
  as my widget is in the **similar-apps-widget** directory in plugins directory.