# Can I have a widget and sidebars in custom theme?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

Wordpress 4.1.1: simular problem to [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149306/wordpress-widget-in-custom-theme):  I have a `add_action` `widgets_init` call back in which I have a call to `register_widget` that registers a class and a call to `register_sidebar` that registers some sidebars.  Only the Widget shows on the Widget admin page.  If I comment out call to `register_widget` the sidebars show.  Can I define a widget *and* sidebars in a theme?

Here is the code from my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function()
{
    // --------------  WIDGETS ---------------------------------------------
    require_once 'MyWidget.php';
    register_widget( 'MyWidget' );

    // --------------  WIDGETS ---------------------------------------------
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Right Sidebar', 'text_domain'),
        'description'   => __('Appears on all pages that have a right sidebar.', 'text_domain'),
        'id'            => 'my-right-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
    ));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE :-). Without seeing your code, it is impossible to help you. Any answer or comment will only be speculation. File an [edit] and add all your relevant code to your question. Tip: If you add code in the editor, highlight all the code and click the `{}` sign in the top right hand corner above the editor once to add your code in a code block

Comment: Are you calling `dynamic_sidebar( 'my-right-sidebar' )` somewhere, for example in `sidebar.php`?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, that is not necessary to make the admin panel display properly.  That is the primary concern given the description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the short answer to the question 'Can you?' = Yes.

Simplicity is an art.  This moved me to dig deeper.

It seems that the admin panel is not good at catching and displaying errors.  What was happening was that the widget definition was throwing within broken markup.  I could only see it if I viewed source.